# Mouse move events on lower div, mouse click on upper

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Has anyone an idea how achieve such a functionality?
I have two absolutely positioned divs in such way:

[image]

And what I want to do is that div1 is listening for mouseover and mouseout events and div2 for mouse click.
When I am moving mouse on div2 the `mouseout` event triggers on div1 and I don't want it to.
I want that user could move a cursor on div2 without triggering div1 `mouseout` (because div1 is behind div2 so actually user did not move a cursor out) and click div2.

I am NOT using a jQuery but is someone could point me how to do this in jQuery and add some details how jQuery is handling such a problem then I will love that answer too ;) but still I prefer jQuery free answer.

Comment: do you actually need to catch the mouseout event on div1 for any reason?

Comment: the idea is that div2 is shown only if mouse enters div1 and disapear if mouse leaves div1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mouseout feature is intended to work so.

You might filter out the behaviour of your mouseout event callback checking if

```
event.relatedTarget != div2
```

rgds

edit: regarding to the click on div2, please comment any further problem you could be experiencing but I don't think there should be any.

Comment: event.target all the time will be fired from div1

Comment: I'm sorry I meant relatedTarget

Answer (score 1):

well, if they are positioned absolutely, you can check the mouse's co-ordinates on mouseout event for div 1. If they are in the rectangle of div 1, prevent it's default behavior that is, don't call the callback function of mouseout event.

Comment: I was considering that but I was wondering if there are some other solution

Answer (score 1):

You're running into a classic even bubbling/capturing issue.

Check out this article: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

It'll be able to explain your situation much better than I ever could!

Here's an exerpt to get you excited:

> The basic problem is very simple. Suppose you have a element inside an
>   element

```
-----------------------------------
| element1                        |
|   -------------------------     |
|   |element2               |     |
|   -------------------------     |
|                                 |
-----------------------------------
```

> and both have an onClick event handler. If the user clicks on element2 he causes a click event in
>   both element1 and element2. But which event fires first? Which event
>   handler should be executed first? What, in other words, is the event
>   order?

Comment: click event will fired on both only if they are parent and child (bubbling concept)

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you can nest div 1 and div 2, you can emulate IEs proprietary mouseenter / mouseleave events, which are more useful than the standard mouseover / mouseout ones. jQuery has methods to emulate them through [.mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [.mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/); their implementation might help you along the way.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/kXjRM

EDIT: have you otherwise considered using CSS instead of JS? As in nesting them and using

```
#two {
  display: none;
}

#one:hover #two {
  display:block;
}
```

?

Comment: Thats pretty nice idea with CSS, I needed JS as it was little more than simple show/hide but I realy like the CSS version ;)